# QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method "Wkhtmltopdf " odoo

Tags: report, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

when i print my report i get this error , i don't know how to solve it 
this is the error

> Rapport (PDF
>   Wkhtmltopdf a échoué (code d'erreur : -11). Message : QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
>   QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method

[image]

Comment: Is there a full stack trace ? If yes please post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is reported on wkhtmltopdf repo:

1. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1516
2. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2431

Make sure you have ssl libs properly installed and that you are using the correct wkhtmltopdf version (should be 0.12.1 on odoo)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the system entry parameters  **web.base.url** you can find in the following menu

```
Settings --> Parameters --> System Parameters
```